# Why does Ganta have hexagons around his blast?

Tags: deadman-wonderland

In Deadman Wonderland, Ganta first has hexagons around his blast when the ball falls from the tower and is about to crush him. Later he gets it again when fighting and protecting Shiro.

[image: Ganta shooting his Ganta Gun with blue hexagons encircling his arm]

The only other person who I know can do this is the Wretched Egg. So why is Ganta able to do it and have a lot more power behind his shot?

Comment: I added an image to show people, I presume this is what you meant?

Comment: yeah that is what I meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really explained in the show. As you can see, in the image below, the Branch of Sins manifestation is based on the power of the user.

[image]

However, if we take Episode 1 into consideration, we can see that Wretched Egg attacks Ganta and kills off his class mates. This is also what seems to be when Ganta should be receiving his powers. In that case, since Wretched Egg's powers have the hexagonal patterns around his/her abilities, then this would explain why Ganta has the same design, since Ganta got his abilities from Wretched Egg.

Comment: Just confirming, the middle image is Ganta aswell? it has a hexagon underneath

Comment: No it is not. That is Nagi Kengamine. It's possible that only those that directly received the power from Wretched Egg have the hexagon. However, that is only speculation since we don't know how exactly all of the branch of sins are distributed.

Comment: Okay i can see that. it sucks that they don't explain it in the show.